# How can I render a moving circle over a video which positions itself based on data from a text file?

Tags: matlab, video, image-processing, matlab-cvst

I have some video (.mp4), and some text data which includes the XY coordinates of a circle that I wish to draw over the video's frames and render a new video.

I have been able to do this in MATLAB using the computer vision toolbox, however the formats of video I can use are extremely limited... I need another method.

Comment: what version of MATLAB do you use?

Comment: If you cannot read a video using `vision.VideoFileReader` it may be because your system does not have the right codec installed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `insertShape` function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.